# sudo pip install PIL and error code 1

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pip

```
mac-cordreys-macbook-pro:~ maccordrey$ sudo pip install PIL
/usr/local/bin/pip:5: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
/usr/local/bin/pip:5: UserWarning: Module site was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
Downloading/unpacking PIL
  Running setup.py egg_info for package PIL
    /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path
      from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
    /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module site was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path
      from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
Installing collected packages: PIL
  Running setup.py install for PIL
    /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path
      from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
    /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module site was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path
      from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
    WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py
    --- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
    building '_imaging' extension
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DMACOSX -I/usr/include/ffi -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -pipe -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/_imaging.o
    unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/maccordrey/build/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-5EOlVp-record/install-record.txt:
    /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module pkg_resources was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path

  from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory

/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py:3: UserWarning: Module site was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages is being added to sys.path

  from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory

WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only.-separated package names in setup.py

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks

building '_imaging' extension

gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DMACOSX -I/usr/include/ffi -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -pipe -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/_imaging.o

unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/maccordrey/build/PIL/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-5EOlVp-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/maccordrey/.pip/pip.log
mac-cordreys-macbook-pro:~ maccordrey$
```

Any ideas? I'm not really sure why I'm receiving this error? I've just begun using PIP an haven't had any problems yet, do I need to move the tar file out of my downloads folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Python packages require building from source. Doing so requires `gcc`, which on OS X is provided by XCode. If you don't have XCode installed, [install it](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install a `gcc` compiler to build PIL. It is better to install PIL, using system's package. For example in Ubuntu you have to run `sudo apt-get install python-imaging`.

On OSX try to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and run `brew install pil`.

Comment: Also, Homebrew requires XCode to be installed anyway, so it'd just be pointless fluff.

Comment: It is not pointless, because homebrew will handle all dependencies, if any.

Comment: So will `pip` - have you ever used `pip` at all before?

Comment: pip does not handle binary dependencies. It is only able to install python packages. PIL requires some C libs like `libjpeg`, `freetype` and `little-cms` and `brew` will build them for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need XCode installed to get gcc installed, which is what your missing.